# Call PHP script from bash from different machine

Tags: php, shell, sh

I need to call a PHP script on machine1 from a `.sh` script on machine2. How can I do this?
Basically I need to pass a parameter to the respective PHP script and make it run using it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ssh:

```
ssh user@otherhost /path/to/php-script
```

if you want to do this in a script, you have to enable public key authentiction.

Comment: And how do I pass a parameter to it? (e.g. `phpfile.php?param=1234`)

Comment: You pass arguments with `ssh user@otherhost /path/to/php-script argument1 argument2 foo bar`. Ensure that the file begins with a sheband (#!/usr/bin/php). The context is the command line, so you don't access arguments via `$_GET` or `$_POST` but via `$argv` (just like in C). Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Answer (score 2):

Setup Apache and use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), or use SSH as the other answer suggested. The security aspects of setting up Apache seems simpler at first, but this may not be true.